# RequireJS Load Module Gone Wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Using RequireJS, I was planning to load a module only in certain page, for example my home page, like this (for the sake of reading, i have translated my code from coffeescript to javascript):

```
require(["tmp/assets/scripts/modules/_image"], function(_image) {
  return $('ul li img')._image.basicImageHover();
});
```

and im my `_image.js` file:

```
$.fn.basicImageHover = function() {
  $(this).on('hover', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('div.caption').slideUp('fast');
    return $(this).css('opacity', '.5');
  });
  return this;
};
```

my project structure is like this (sorry i don't know how to draw better graphs):

> - tmp/assets/scripts/modules/_image.js
> - tmp/assets/scripts/front/home.js

error in my console said that at `home.js` the `_image` is undefined, i'm guessing by changing the module to return function instead of plugin might work, but i was wondering what could be wrong with my current setup. Can anyone help explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code.

First, there's the problem of how to access a jQuery plugin. These install themselves on jQuery objects, so you won't get them through RequireJS. This code in particular does not do what you think it does:

```
require(["tmp/assets/scripts/modules/_image"], function(_image) {
  return $('ul li img')._image.basicImageHover();
});
```

The part `$('ul li img')._image.basicImageHover()` is going to be evaluated to get the field named `_image` from the value returned by `$('ul li img')`. This has *nothing* to do whatsoever with the value of the `_image` argument of your function. What you need is this:

```
require(["tmp/assets/scripts/modules/_image"], function() {
  $('ul li img').basicImageHover();
});
```

I've removed `return` because it is completely useless in a callback passed to `require`. (There's nowhere sensible to return the value. RequireJS receives the value but it goes nowhere after this.) There's no need for the `_image` argument because the jQuery plugin you show in your code installs itself on instances of `jQuery`.

Second, your `_image.js` file should call `define` to be AMD-compliant:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

  $.fn.basicImageHover = function() {
    $(this).on('hover', function() {
      $(this).parent().find('div.caption').slideUp('fast');
      return $(this).css('opacity', '.5');
    });
  };
});
```

I've removed the `return` statement because it serves no purpose here either. The code above entails that you must configure RequireJS to know where to get jQuery and load it. If you are in a situation where jQuery is loaded *outside* and *before* RequireJS, then you could make the `define` be `define([], function () {`.

Comment: never mind my comment below, it's jquery issue and already solved, thanks for the answer

Comment: Glad to help. You should remove that comment you posted as an answer before people downvote it and vote to delete it. (By the way, I see you wrote `@Louis` in that post but the SO software did not notify me. I believe that `@username` does not work in answers)